# Can Mockito capture an argument of a variable declarated in implementation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, verify

I have the class implementation:

```
public class testImpl{
  public void method(Object a){
    Object obj = new Object();
    PrintWritter printW = a.getWriter();
    printW.append(obj.toString());
  }
}
```

How can I capture the value of "obj" when printW execute the method "append"?

Comment: You cannot capture the obj, since it's not propagated outside the method. You will only be able to get the result of `obj.ToString()` using ArgumentCaptor on Object a.append

Comment: maybe `PowerMockito` can do this, though I am not entirely sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have two options:

1. Mock `PrintWriter` and capture `obj.toString()` when `append` is called. However, this will only give you the `String` representation of the `Object` and not the actual object, e.g.:

   ```
   PrintWriter mockWriter = Mockito.mock(PrintWriter.class);
   Object mockA = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
   Mockito.when(mockA.getWriter()).thenReturn(mockWriter);
   ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
   verify(mockWriter).append(argument.capture());
   String result = argument.getValue();
   ```
2. Use `PowerMockito` and mock a constructor for the class of your local variable, e.g.:

   ```
   Object mockObject = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
   PowerMockito.whenNew(Object.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockObject);
   ```

   You will have to annotate the junit class with `@PrepareForTest(Object.class)`.

Comment: Are you sure that second way works? Did you try?